# How well does Windows 8 RTM run on rMBP via BootCamp

Tags: windows, bootcamp, macbook-pro

How is Windows RTM running on Retina MBP via BootCamp?

- Are all the Windows 8 touchpad gestures working?
- How well does Win8 display on the retina screen resolution?
- Are there any other serious incompatibilities that you've found?

Answer (score 3):

I'm having a lot of problems running Metro Apps, some of them crash or fail to load.

Contacted microsoft via microsoft answers and they told me that the broadcom bluetooth may cause the problem.  The driver is from 2009, I'm trying to get an updated driver from apple or other source.

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.tattoocoder.com/2012/08/upgrading-from-windows-7-to-windows-8.html

Had some issues with the multi touch track pad, but uninstalling BootCamp and reinstalling everything went well. Performs great! Looks great.  Couldn't be happier.  I am a developer and I run SQL Server 2012 and Visual Studio 2012 on here as well with no issues.  All RTM releases.